# How to read from file in Java using Scanner?

Tags: java, android, file

I have an text ("Contacts.txt") file like this:

> Pedro Melendez 7823455555 9395554444 myEmail@stack.com
>
> Bob Ramirez 8725551234 9452455543 bob.ramirez@stack.com
>
> Luis González 8907653456 null luis.gonzalez@stack.com

Is a text file where I will save the contacts information of people. (Is for an android application)

I have to save this contacts information in to a  list of type Contact (List). The contact have the following variables:

- firstName
- lastName
- cellPhone
- workPhone
- email

How I can use the Scanner to save the information in the text file in the list?

I used this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Contacts.txt");

while(in.hasNextLine()){
        this.contactList.add(new Contact(in.next(), in.next(), in.next(), in.next(), in.next()));
}
```

But that does not work.  Where is the best way to save the information in the List?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to parse the line before you make your new contact

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line= in.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    this.contactList.add(new Contact(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3],tokens[4]))

}
```

I dont really know what your contact constructor looks like since your didn't post it but I assumed its in the order your listed the items.

I also assumed that all the lines look the same, as in they all have all the data in question if not this solution is going to get an out of bound exception.

Comment: I don't think in.next() would work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that but also I have an error (NullPointerException). But I think that what you do is correct. I will be search to find the error. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! yes. The contact constructor have the item in the same order that I listed. Thanks it work now!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is get each line from the text, split the line by a `space` (as each part of the line is separated by a space), create an object with the values you get and save the object to the list.

```
File file = new File("Contacts.txt");
    Scanner in= new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
         String line = in.nextLine();
         String tokens[] = line.split(" ");
         Contact c = new Contact (tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3],tokens[4]) //assume your object is of Contact class
         this.contactList.add(c);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that but also I have an error (NullPointerException). But I think that what you do is correct. I will be search to find the error. Thanks!